# excel 2010 vba loop through declared variabels syntax results in Compile error Variable not defined

Tags: excel, vba, variables, loops, syntax-error

I declared 5 integers

```
    Public Hol_1 as integer
    Public Hol_2 as integer
    Public Hol_3 as integer
    Public Hol_4 as integer
    Public Hol_5 as integer
```

Imagine I have 3 clients, then I will use Hol_1 to Hol_3. This also means: iClients = 3
First thing I need to do is look in my sheets("Holidays") to determine how much holidays each of my 3 clients have.

```
    Sub CountHolidays()

    Dim i as integer
    Dim iclients as integer
    iclients = 3
    For i=1 to iclients 
        Hol_i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Holidays").Range(Cells(2, 3 + i), Cells(50, 3 + i))) 
       'The worksheetfunction calculates the amount of Holiday-dates I have for each of my three clients
    Next i
    End sub
```

I get a compile error saying Variable is not defined:   Hol_i is not defined. I tried "Hol_" & i and others but was not able to correct this. Does anybody has an idea? THX

Answer (score 4):

You cannot concatenate variable names.  `Hol_i` is a completely separate variable from `Hol_1` even when `i=1`.

You need an array to do this:

```
Dim Hol(5) as Integer

For i=1 to iclients 
  Hol(i) = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Holidays").Range(Cells(2, 3 + i), Cells(50, 3 + i)))
Next i
```